# Calling vcvarsall.bat gives "Windows cannot find powershell.exe" on Windows 7 / VS 2019 Build tools

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I previously had Visual Studio 2015 (14.0) Build tools installed, and I could build a simple C++ program, without any IDE, with:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
cl helloworld1.cpp
```

Now that I installed Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools, calling `vcvarsall.bat` gives this message:

> Windows cannot find 'powershell.exe'

but after closing the dialog, it still continues (!). But then it fails with:

> cl : Command line error D8027 : cannot execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\c1xx.dll'

I don't see why powershell would be mandatory to just set a few environments variables and set up everything to use `cl.exe`.

**Question: what's the proper way to call cl.exe with VS Build Tools 2019?**

Shouldn't we call `vcvarsall.bat` first, like with previous versions?

(important: I'm looking for a 100% terminal mode, no IDE)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official way would be to to add `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` to your `PATH` either permanently or just before calling `vcvarsall.bat`.

An alternative is to do a `set VSCMD_SKIP_SENDTELEMETRY=1` before calling `vcvarsall.bat`. This works because `vcvarsall` internally calls `vsdevcmd`, which in turn uses `powershell` to configure "*send telemetry if user's VS is opted-in*". However, the telemetry step is bypassed when `VSCMD_SKIP_SENDTELEMETRY` is defined (though this appears to be undocumented, and thus subject to change in future versions), then `powershell` is no longer used or required.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dxiv, the problem was indeed that I did some "cleaning" in the PATH, and probably removed the PowerShell PATH accidentally...

Comment: For the second part of the question, why could be the reason for `cl : Command line error D8027 : cannot execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\c1xx.dll'` ? This file is present in the filesystem, I wonder why it cannot be executed... Do you have any idea @dxiv?

Comment: @Basj That must have something to do with your build tools setup or configuration. I am using a full VS install and I am not seeing the error, or any errors for that matter. Is the path you quoted the *first* one in your `PATH` environment after `vcvarsall`?